# Relationship Between Determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have problem that is essentially
$$\det \left( I + \eta G^H G \right) = \det (I + G^{H}\gamma G).$$
**Is there any relationship between $\eta$ and $\gamma$** ?

I know:

$\eta$ and $\gamma$ are diagonal matrices, order N and M, respectively.

$G$ is a matrix of order MxN

Comment: $G^H$ is Hermitian conjugate? In general, you should be very explicit about the objects in the questions you ask